# What is the help file format for Mac app?

Tags: cocoa

I want to migrate one of my Windows app to Mac.
As we know, Windows app help file format is .chm.
Does Mac app has special format?
or just the format html?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the documentation? It's a simple static HTML site embedded as a resource. You also use the Help Indexer app (part of Xcode Tools) to create the needed index file then you set a couple of keys in your Info.plist file to tell your app it's there.